# RegEx is matching to wide?

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex

I have a html string, where i need to grab the `src` and `href` values, if they meet a pattern. The pattern is;

```
/myfolder/[gu-id]/[image,file]
```

The gu-id is in the pattern of `'65f2383b-de39-4a9c-8e8c-de1c06e469ca'`
The image or file can be any jpg,gif,pdf,doc,xlsx.png,txt,zip and so on.

My current regex is this: `((\/myfolder\/[({]?[a-fA-F0-9]{8}[-]?([a-fA-F0-9]{4}[-]?){3}[a-fA-F0-9]{12}[})]?\/?.*\.(?:png|jpg|pdf|gif|jpeg|xls|xlsx|word|doc|txt|zip)))`

But in a string with multiple files, it ends with the last one, as the end of the first match - so it only finds one match, but the end point, is another file.

How can I make it match every file, and not only one?

Comment: Change the `.*` to `\S*` See https://regex101.com/r/SjDgfs/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `.*` you could match non whitespace char `\S*`

As a minor note, if you are not using the capturing groups for after processing and want the match only you could omit them. The single hyphen in the character class `[-]?` can be written as `-?`. The forward slash `\/` does not need escaping

The alternation could be shortened a bit to `(?:png|pdf|gif|jpe?g|xlsx?|word|doc|txt|zip)`

You could update the pattern to:

```
/myfolder/[({]?[a-fA-F0-9]{8}-?(?:[a-fA-F0-9]{4}-?){3}[a-fA-F0-9]{12}[})]?/?\S*\.(?:png|pdf|gif|jpe?g|xlsx?|word|doc|txt|zip)
```

[.NET Regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%2fmyfolder%2f%5b%28%7b%5d%3f%5ba-fA-F0-9%5d%7b8%7d-%3f%28%3f%3a%5ba-fA-F0-9%5d%7b4%7d-%3f%29%7b3%7d%5ba-fA-F0-9%5d%7b12%7d%5b%7d%29%5d%3f%2f%3f%5cS*%5c.%28%3f%3apng%7cpdf%7cgif%7cjpe%3fg%7cxlsx%3f%7cword%7cdoc%7ctxt%7czip%29&i=%2fmyfolder%2f65f2383b-de39-4a9c-8e8c-de1c06e469ca%2ffile.png+%2fmyfolder%2f65f2383b-de39-4a9c-8e8c-de1c06e469ca%2ffile.png)